# SQL ANY and ALL operators seem illogical to me. What am I missing?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to learn SQL from online course ([link to lesson](https://www.coursera.org/learn/database-structures-and-management-with-mysql/supplement/Vw192/reading-exercise-operators-and-clauses-optional)) and can't understand the solution to exercise related to ANY operator. There are two tables:

- `employees`       with columns EmployeeID and EmployeeName
- `employee_orders` with columns EmployeeID, OrderID and Status

**Goal**: Use the ANY operator to identify all employees with the Order Status status 'Completed' (i.e. all employess who have completed at least one order). The **solution**:

```
SELECT EmployeeId, EmployeeName  
FROM employees  
WHERE EmployeeID = ANY (SELECT EmployeeID FROM employee_orders WHERE Status='Completed');
```

**My problem**: According to MySQL docs:

> The ANY keyword, which must follow a comparison operator, means “return TRUE if the comparison is TRUE for ANY of the values in the column that the subquery returns.”

Based on that my understanding of condition after WHERE is:

1. "EmployeeID must be equal to True/False returned by ANY "function" (I am aware that operators in SQL might not work like composite fuctions but I don't understand why and what happens inside instead.)
2. "EmployeeID must be any of ids selected by subquery". Why don't we just use IN operator instead of ANY?
3. If we replace ANY with ALL then "EmployeeID must be any of ids selected by subquery" which has no sense.

Comment: `ANY` and `ALL` are rarely used IME. `= ANY` is equivalent to `IN`. But `ANY`/`ALL` aren't restricted to `=`

Comment: Never used them ever, they are pretty much superflous.

Comment: ANY == SOME, and it means "at least one of". I.e. "there exists a value which is equal, and it is any of the values".

Comment: @Stu Nor me. `IS DISTINCT FROM ALL` does gives another option for a `NOT IN` analogue that treats `NULL` differently though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANY modifies the operator (`=` in the example case) to basically loop over the subquery results.  So your `EmployeeID = ANY (SELECT EmployeeID ...)` does the subquery, then loops over the resulting rows, and the `= ANY` operation returns true for any employees row where the EmployeeID equals at least one of the selected employee_orders EmployeeID.  It is not useful to think of ANY as returning anything; it only modifies another operator.

In the given example, `IN` would be much clearer and usually be used instead.

If you replace ANY with ALL, you are saying to return employees info only if the employee has a completed order and no other employee has a completed order.

Does that help?

Another example of ANY: only select employees whose salary is less than the average salary of any department:

```
select employee_id, salary
from employees
where salary < any(select avg(salary) from employees group by department_id)
```

There, the equivalent non-any query is more complex (but still probably easier to understand):

```
select employee_id, salary
from employees
where salary < (select max(avg_salary) from (select avg(salary) avg_salary from employees group by department_id) avg_salaries)
```

Comment: "If you replace ANY with ALL, you are saying to return employees info only if the employee has a completed order and no other employee has a completed order." - I don't understand this part - for me it would mean "return employee info only all their orders are completed (which btw wouldn't work in case of this table because for each completed order it contains also it's version with "In progress" status, i.e. old records aren't deleted when status changes).

Everythig else is clear and helpful.

Comment: The subquery isn't restricted to just that employee.  It returns all ids of employees who have any completed orders. And then employeeId=ALL will return false if any of those is different.  So  =ALL will always be false if more than one employee has a completed order, or no employees have completed orders.  If only one employee has completed orders, it will be true for that employee and false for others.